# Change SELECT statement with CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns data like this:

**Data**

```
|Nbr|Type|TelNbr|PNbr|Date|
|12345|AA|001122|432|15-DEC-14|
|23456|AA|009933|567|21-SEP-01|
|99999|AA|885523|000|17-JUN-98|
|99999|BB|885523|000|21-FEB-94|
|65432|AA|112233|NULL|01-JAN-01|
|NULL|AA|333333|555|09-JUL-20|
|65432|BB|112233|888|06-MAY-08|
|01010|CC|333333|555|04-MAR-99|
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.Nbr
,t1.Type
,MAX(FUNCTION(t1.TelNbr)) TelNbr
,t2.PNbr
,MIN(t1.Date)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.Nbr, t1.Type, t2.PNbr
```

I want expand upon this query to select the oldest row (`MIN(t1.Date)`) **for each TelNbr instance** where type equals `AA`. However, if `Nbr` or `PNbr` is NULL, then I want to select the oldest row regardless of the type **for each TelNbr instance**.

I attempted to do something like this, but I'm not great with CASE statements:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Nbr IS NULL OR t2.PNbr IS NULL
THEN SELECT t1.Nbr
, t1.Type
, MAX(FUNCTION(TelNbr) TelNbr
, t2.PNbr
, MIN(t1.Date) 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Nbr, t1.Type, t1.TelNbr, t2.PNbr
ELSE SELECT t1.Nbr
, t1.Type
, MAX(FUNCTION(TelNbr) TelNbr
, t2.PNbr
, MIN(t1.Date)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Type = 'AA' 
GROUP BY t1.Nbr, t1.Type, t1.TelNbr, t2.PNbr
END
```

Whenever I run the query, Oracle gives me the following error:

`ORA-00936: missing expression`

Is my syntax off? I’ve tried to find the answer online, but I’m not having any luck. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: For each SELECT you need exactly one FROM.

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Comment: If you write a query with 3 SELECT but only 2 FROM, something is wrong. (ANSI SQL and Oracle have this syntax. Some products allow a SELECT without a FROM.)

Comment: So do I need to add `FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id` after the end of my CASE? I tried that and I get the same error

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out what you're doing here.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to return the the first entry ever for each `TelNbr` that has a type of AA. But if an entry has a NULL value in `Nbr` OR `PNbr` then I just want the first entry ever for that `TelNbr` regardless of type (so it doesn't have to be AA).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid. You can use conditional aggregation in an analytic `COUNT` function and then filter the rows in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN nbr IS NULL OR pnbr IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER ()
           AS null_count
  FROM   table_name t
  ORDER BY "DATE" asc
)
WHERE ( null_count > 0 OR type = 'AA' )
AND   ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I expanded upon my question a bit as it may have been a little misleading. I use a query to retrieve the data poised in the question and I want to expand upon my original query. I tried using your approach, but I have a join in my original query and I'm having a hard time updating my original query with your logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`CASE statement` is not used for switching of SELECT data group as you are trying to achieve. In your case, you could use UNION (or UNION ALL) for selecting desired output from 2 data groups.

```
-- Group 1: data which has Nbr or PNbr is null.
SELECT Nbr, Type, TelNbr, PNbr, MIN(DateTime)  
FROM data
WHERE (Nbr IS NULL OR PNbr IS NULL)
GROUP BY Nbr, Type, TelNbr, PNbr   
-- Group 2: data which has Type = 'AA' and Nbr, PNbr is not null.                   
UNION ALL
SELECT Nbr, Type, TelNbr, PNbr, MIN(DateTime) 
FROM data
WHERE Type = 'AA' AND Nbr IS NOT NULL AND PNbr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Nbr, Type, TelNbr, PNbr
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b519d/240

Comment: This query only returned one row. Why is that? Even when I view your sqlfiddle, it only returns two rows

Comment: Maybe I should have expanded a little bit more. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear of your expected output, but I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear (no expected result) what do you want but, as  I understand the question, it seems like you want 2 rows as a result - one for type 'AA' with oldest date and the other (if there are Nulls in NBR or PNBR) with absolute oldest date.
Below is the code that results like described and giving you some options to get different results.
SAMPLE DATA:

```sql
    tbl (NBR, A_TYPE, TELNBR, PNBR, A_DATE) AS
        (
            Select  '12345', 'AA', '001122', '432',  DATE '2014-12-15' From Dual Union All
            Select  '23456', 'AA', '009933', '567',  DATE '2001-09-21' From Dual Union All
            Select  '99999', 'AA', '885523', '000',  DATE '1998-06-17' From Dual Union All
            Select  '99999', 'BB', '885523', '000',  DATE '1994-02-21' From Dual Union All
            Select  '65432', 'AA', '112233', Null,   DATE '2001-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select  Null,    'AA', '333333', '555',  DATE '2020-07-09' From Dual Union All
            Select  '65432', 'BB', '112233', '888',  DATE '2008-05-06' From Dual Union All
            Select  '01010', 'CC', '333333', '555',  DATE '1999-03-04' From Dual 
        )
```

**SQL 1**

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM
    (
        SELECT      t.A_TYPE "A_TYPE", 
                    t.NBR, t.TELNBR, t.PNBR, 
                    CASE WHEN t.NBR Is Null OR t.PNBR Is Null THEN MIN(t.A_DATE) OVER() ELSE dt.MIN_DATE END "MIN_DATE" ,
                    MIN(t.A_DATE) OVER() "ABS_MIN_DATE"
        FROM        tbl t
        INNER JOIN  
            ( Select    CASE WHEN NBR Is Null OR PNBR Is Null THEN 'AA' ELSE A_TYPE END "A_TYPE", 
                        MIN(A_DATE) "MIN_DATE"
              From      tbl
              Group By  CASE WHEN NBR Is Null OR PNBR Is Null THEN 'AA' ELSE A_TYPE END
            ) dt ON(dt.MIN_DATE = t.A_DATE And dt.A_TYPE = CASE WHEN t.NBR Is Null OR t.PNBR Is Null THEN 'AA' ELSE t.A_TYPE END )
        ORDER BY  t.A_TYPE
    )
WHERE   A_TYPE = 'AA' OR MIN_DATE = ABS_MIN_DATE

AA
A_TYPE NBR   TELNBR PNBR MIN_DATE  ABS_MIN_DATE
------ ----- ------ ---- --------- ------------
AA     99999 885523 000  17-JUN-98 21-FEB-94    
BB     99999 885523 000  21-FEB-94 21-FEB-94
```

You can exclude the last column from the selection - I left it here intentionaly so you could compare it with next SQL where just the values of 'AA' within the case expressions are changed into 'XX'.

**SQL 2**

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM
    (
        SELECT      t.A_TYPE "A_TYPE", 
                    t.NBR, t.TELNBR, t.PNBR, 
                    CASE WHEN t.NBR Is Null OR t.PNBR Is Null THEN MIN(t.A_DATE) OVER() ELSE dt.MIN_DATE END "MIN_DATE" ,
                    MIN(t.A_DATE) OVER() "ABS_MIN_DATE"
        FROM        tbl t
        INNER JOIN  
            ( Select    CASE WHEN NBR Is Null OR PNBR Is Null THEN 'XX' ELSE A_TYPE END "A_TYPE", 
                        MIN(A_DATE) "MIN_DATE"
              From      tbl
              Group By  CASE WHEN NBR Is Null OR PNBR Is Null THEN 'XX' ELSE A_TYPE END
            ) dt ON(dt.MIN_DATE = t.A_DATE And dt.A_TYPE = CASE WHEN t.NBR Is Null OR t.PNBR Is Null THEN 'XX' ELSE t.A_TYPE END )
        ORDER BY  t.A_TYPE
    )
WHERE   A_TYPE = 'AA' OR MIN_DATE = ABS_MIN_DATE

XX
A_TYPE NBR   TELNBR PNBR MIN_DATE  ABS_MIN_DATE
------ ----- ------ ---- --------- ------------
AA     99999 885523 000  17-JUN-98 21-FEB-94    
AA     65432 112233      21-FEB-94 21-FEB-94    
BB     99999 885523 000  21-FEB-94 21-FEB-94
```

**SQL 3** - Min date per TELNBR for type 'AA'

```sql
Select    A_TYPE,   
          TELNBR,
          MIN(A_DATE) "MIN_DATE"
From      tbl
WHERE A_TYPE = 'AA'
Group By  A_TYPE, TELNBR
```

| A_TYPE | TELNBR | MIN_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 112233 | 01-JAN-01 |
| AA | 885523 | 17-JUN-98 |
| AA | 009933 | 21-SEP-01 |
| AA | 333333 | 09-JUL-20 |
| AA | 001122 | 15-DEC-14 |

**SQL 4**  - same as 3 but with all columns

```sql
SELECT m.A_TYPE, m.TELNBR, m.MIN_DATE, t.NBR, t.PNBR
FROM   (  Select    A_TYPE, TELNBR, MIN(A_DATE) "MIN_DATE"
          From      tbl 
          WHERE A_TYPE = 'AA'
          Group By  A_TYPE, TELNBR  
       ) m
LEFT JOIN tbl t ON(t.A_TYPE = m.A_TYPE And t.TELNBR = m.TELNBR And t.A_DATE = m.MIN_DATE)
```

| A_TYPE | TELNBR | MIN_DATE | NBR | PNBR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 001122 | 15-DEC-14 | 12345 | 432 |
| AA | 009933 | 21-SEP-01 | 23456 | 567 |
| AA | 885523 | 17-JUN-98 | 99999 | 000 |
| AA | 112233 | 01-JAN-01 | 65432 |  |
| AA | 333333 | 09-JUL-20 |  | 555 |

Comment: I apologize, I should have expanded more on my question. I am trying to get the oldest row where type equals `AA` for each TelNbr instance. So it'll definitely be more than two rows. I explained what I was trying to get further in my question. Hopefully I explained it better.

Comment: @Crimp - Just added SQL 3 and SQL 4...